# ASP.NET rebuilding javascript files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Debugging my asp.net webpage requires a simple save. From there I can just refresh my page to view my changes to the webpage. However Ive noticed that javascript scripts outside of the aspx file don't update. When I refresh my browser the javascript files don't update when I save changes to them. So my question is how do I get the compiler to rebuild my javascripts and deploy them? Im using visual studio 2010. Is there some setting to make this automatically happen if not how do I get VS to compile or deploy these javascripts to the browser? Build website/ Build solution / Rebuild don't work by the way neither does running debug.

To add the file im using:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  src="../UserControls/JavaScript/Comment.js"></script>
```

if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the browser caching the files?

Comment: Also are you using bundles? if so the bundles need to be recompiled every time one of the files within them changes.

Comment: I just tried it on 3 other browsers and that was not the issue. And Im not using bundles. =/

Comment: How you compile your javascript files ? How you include this files on your page ?

Comment: Is this IE we're having trouble with? IE would cache a dead horse.

Comment: Nope im using Firefox and occasionally chrome.

Comment: Usually with Firefox or Chrome I do a hard refresh: ctrl+reload. And that takes care of cached script.

Comment: @Jasen Your a master sir ctrl+reload worked. Thank you sir and everyone else who tried to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does not need to be compiled by VS2010 for ASP.NET.  It is compiled locally on the browser.

If it's caching, for IE10 (which I assume you are using with VS2010), hit F12 (Developer Tools).  The second icon from the left shows a window with a red X, which clears the cache for development.  Click that, wait for the cache to completely clear, close IE10, and get back in.  In some cases, you may need to restart IIS or clear the development server from the system tray.

Otherwise, be sure you're saving the correct JavaScript files.  If you're deploying it to a remote server, be sure the JavaScript files are deployed, and then the browser cache cleared.

Comment: Im using Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: With IE this sometimes isn't enough and I need to restart IIS or kill the development server in the system tray. Still, this is useful.

Comment: @OzzyWe -- In Chrome, go to Settings (from the icon on the top right).  Then click "Clear browsing data...".

Comment: @Jasen -- Good point--I edited my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: This is what worked for me (using Chrome): using CTRL + F5 for refreshing clears the caches and thus it rebuilds the JavaScript sources.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**Goto IE(I am using IE11) In that Settings->Interenet options->General Tab->Browsing history ->Setting change it to Every time i visit the webpage.**